# Could AAR archive contain compiled classes?

Tags: apache-axis

is it possible to have compiled classes inside AAR file?

```
archive.aar
+-META-INF/ (wsdls + service.xml)
+-com/example/GeneratedArtifactFromWSDL.class
```

My question is, whether other classes in different classes could use those generated classes if archive.aar is on classpath. And second question, is Axis able to handle such archive? Or is my only way to generate 2 archives - aar with wsdls and service.xml and jar with compiled classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal to include compiled classes specific to a service in the AAR file for the service. It's done exactly as in your example. When Axis2 runs your service, it provides a classloader that can access the contents of the AAR.

[Here is some documentation](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html#services) on the layout of AAR files.